# Meaning of LineElement in Mathematica?

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

Line element in mathematics is generally defined as the following:

$\qquad ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2$

In Mathematica, the documentation of `LineElement` says:

> $\mathtt{LineElement}[{{i_{1_1}, i_{1_2}}, …,{i_{n_1}, i_{n_2}}}]$ represents $n$ linear line elements $e_k$ with incidents ${i_{k_1}, i_{k_2}}$.

What is meant by "incidents ${i_{k_1},i_{k_2}}$"?

Does this mean the line elements joining all these points in a plane?

Comment: `LineElement`s are an element type for a finite element method mesh to be used in `NDSolve`.  See the documentation for [ToElementMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToElementMesh.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

As Tim pointed out in the comments, the `LineElement` is a finite element. If you open the ref page of `LineElement` and click on the "Details" section, you will find more information. Alternatively you can paste this

```
LineElement#921078465
```

in your help system.

Comment: Yeah, I finally realized what was going on, i_k_1 etc stand for integers which represent the coordinates one add for the function ToBoundaryMesh for example. So if the coordinates are {0.0}.{1.1}.{1.2} and the line element is {1,3} then the corresponding line has {0,0} and {1,2} as end points.